# getLineCount of TextView with Runnable not working properly in Adapter

Tags: android, adapter, textview

I am developing an Android application. My app has news feed list like Facebook. I am setting readmore feature if the text of TextView is too long for each post. I am using ExpandableTextView for readmore feature. But it is ok.

Then problem is with getting line count of TextView. I need to know the line count after I set the text to TextView because I need to toggle the visibility of Read more button. But getLineCount is not working well.

In the bindViewHolder of Recycler adapter, I set the text to TextView like this:

```
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(post.getTitle());
        viewHolder.tvTitle.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("LINE_COUNT_"+String.valueOf(position),String.valueOf(viewHolder.tvTitle.getLineCount()));
                if(viewHolder.tvTitle.getLineCount()>=3)
                {
                    viewHolder.tvReadmore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    viewHolder.tvReadmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

As you can see, I am using runnable because getLineCount() of TextView always returns 0 if I do not use it. But when I run my code and see my app, getLineCount() is working only for first 2 or 3 items. Not working for the rest of the items. I log the line count in the code. This is what I get in logcat. See the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see in the logcat, it is returning value only for the first 2 items. For the rest of items, it always returns 0. Actually, all TextViews in the list has text line at least one. Some have 4 or 5. But it is not working. The runnable does not work well in RecyclerView Adapter? How can I fix my code to get the correct line count of textview in adapter?

Comment: Did you fix it? I need soulution:-)

Comment: i am facing similar problem .. have you find any solution?